# How to refresh pull-down menus in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

I have 3 pull down menus (Clients, Locations, Dock), the information of all three comes from the database.  First I select a client, then I select a location, and then I select a dock; fields do not support multiple options selection; only one option can be selected per field.

For Example....
If I select Client1, the Locations of Client1 get populated and appear in the Locations pull-down menu field, then when I select a Location (let say Location1), the Docks for Location1 appear in the Docks field.

However, If I go back to the Clients field and select Client2, the fields Locations and Docks do no refresh and do not display the data related to Client2. the fields still show the information related to Client1.  How do I refresh the fields to Display the Locations of Client2 and the Docks for Location2?

I am using JSP and AngularJS

```
    <div class="params">
        <div class="blankLine20px"></div>
        <div style='float: left; padding-right: 10px'>
            <span style="padding: 2px 5px; font-weight: bold"> Select
                Customer </span> <select style="width: 200px; z-index: 100;"
                id="select-customer"
                ng-options="value.label for (key, value) in customers"
                ng-model="customer">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style='float: left; padding-right: 10px'>
            <span style="padding: 2px 5px; font-weight: bold"> Select
                Location </span> <select style="width: 200px; z-index: 100;"
                id="select-location"
                ng-options="value.label for (key, value) in locations"
                ng-model="location">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>    
        <div style='float: left; padding-right: 10px'>
            <span style="padding: 2px 5px; font-weight: bold"> Select
                Dock </span> <select style="width: 200px; z-index: 100;"
                id="select-dock"
                ng-options="value.label for (key, value) in docks"
                ng-model="dock">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style='float: left; padding-right: 10px'>
            <span style="padding: 4px 5px; font-weight: bold"> Select
                Period to View </span> <input type="text" id="dateRange"
                ng-model="dateRange" class="text" />
        </div>
        <div style='float: left; padding-right: 10px'>
            <input class="fancy-button submit" type="button" value="View"
                id="buttonSetPeriod" />
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is the controllers.js file...

```
<pre>
var baseCtrl = application.controller('baseCtrl', [
        '$location',
        '$element',
        '$rootScope',
        '$scope',
        'baseService',
        '$contextService',
        '$timeout',
        function($location, $element, $rootScope, $scope, baseService, $contextService, $timeout) {
            var url = $location.absUrl();
            $rootScope.currentUrl = url;
            var splitUrl = url.split('/');
            var baseUrl = '';
            var brk = 2;
            if (splitUrl.length > 3) {
                brk = 3;
            }
            var i = 0;
            try {
                splitUrl.forEach(function(part) {
                    baseUrl += part + '/';
                    if (i === brk)
                        throw Exception();
                    i++;
                });
            } 
            catch (e) {
            }
            baseUrl = baseUrl.replace('index.php', '');
            $rootScope.baseUrl = baseUrl;

            // Setting default to null.
            $scope.customer = null;

            // Calling service for customer population. service.js =>
            // $contextService
            var customers = $contextService.getCustomers();

            customers.$promise.then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.customers = data;
                $timeout(function() {
                    $('#select-customer').chosen();
                }, 500);

            });

            $scope.$watch('customer', function(nv, ov) {
                if (nv) {
                    var locations = $contextService.getLocations(nv);
                    locations.$promise.then(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.locations = data;
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $('#select-location').chosen();
                        }, 500);
                    });
                }
            });

            $scope.$watch('location', function(nv, ov) {
                if (nv) {
                    var docks = $contextService.getDocks(nv);
                    docks.$promise.then(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.docks = data;
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $('#select-dock').chosen();
                        }, 500);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    ]
);
</pre>
```

and this is the service.js file.  This is the service.js file for customer, locations, docks...

```
<pre>
var baseService = application.service('baseService', [ '$location',
        '$rootScope', '$injector', function($location, $rootScope, $injector) {
            var _extended = [];
            return {
                setFormData : function() {
                    $rootScope.dateRange = $("#dateRange").val();
                    $rootScope.selectedDock = $("#dropdownDocks").val();
                    $rootScope.formData = {
                        selectedDock : $rootScope.selectedDock,
                        dateRange : $rootScope.dateRange
                    };
                },
                Extended : _extended
            };
        } ]);

var dashboardSvc = application.service('dashboardSvc', [ 'baseService',
        '$rootScope', function(baseService, $rootScope) {

            return {

            };
        } ]);

var kpiSvc = application.service('kpiSvc', [ 'baseService', '$rootScope',
        '$resource', function(baseService, $rootScope, $resource) {
            var $kpi = $resource('kpi/:p1/:p2', {
                p1 : '@p1',
                p2 : '@p2'
            }, {
                savem : {
                    method : 'POST',
                    isArray : true
                }
            });

            this.Get = function(form) {
                if (form !== null) {
                    return $kpi.save({
                        p1 : form.groupType,
                        p2 : form.rangeType
                    }, form, function(o, head) {
                        console.log(o);
                    });
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            };
        } ]);

var $contextService = application.service('$contextService', [ '$resource',
        function($resource) {

            var $context = $resource('./context/:param1/:param2', {
                param1 : '@param1',
                param2 : '@param2'
            }, {
                savem : {
                    method : 'POST',
                    isArray : true
                }
            });

            this.getCustomers = function() {
                return $context.get({
                    param1 : 'customers'
                }, function(o, head) {
                }, function(o, head) {
                    console.log(o);
                });
            };

            this.getLocations = function(customer) {
                return $context.save({
                    param1 : 'locations'
                }, customer, function(o, head) {
                }, function(o, head) {
                    console.log(o);
                });
            };

            this.getDocks = function(location) {
                return $context.save({
                    param1 : 'docks'
                }, location, function(o, head) {
                }, function(o, head) {
                    console.log(o);
                });
            };

            this.getSubDocks = function(dock) {
                return $context.save({
                    param1 : 'subdocks'
                }, dock, function(o, head) {
                }, function(o, head) {
                    console.log(o);
                });
            };

        } ]);
```

Comment: Can you post the js file or wherever you're storing information for the values `customers`, `locations`, and `docks`?

Comment: Yes I can......  Give me a sec please

Comment: @sahilkmr78 : I just posted the controllers.js file and service.js file

Comment: Anyone?  I really need to get this fixed  :(

Comment: No one knows the answer to this?  I am shocked, most of the times there are answers on any topic.